# Conditions in stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Here's my code

```
    public String marks(Double d){
    if (d>90)
        return "A";
    else if (90>=d&&d>=83)
        return "B";
    else if (83>d&&d>=75)
        return "C";
    else if (75>d&&d>=68)
        return "D";
    else if (68>d&&d>=60)
        return "E";
    else
        return "F";


}

public Map<Person, String> defineMarks(Stream<CourseResult> results) {
    return results.collect(Collectors.toMap(CourseResult::getPerson,x->marks(x.getTaskResults().values().stream().mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue).average().orElse(0))));
}
```

And here's CourseResult class for reference.

```
public class CourseResult {
private final Person person;
private final Map<String, Integer> taskResults;

public CourseResult(final Person person, final Map<String, Integer> taskResults) {
    this.person = person;
    this.taskResults = taskResults;
}

public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}

public Map<String, Integer> getTaskResults() {
    return taskResults;
}
```

}

So my defineMarks method returns a map of persons with marks they got for their respective scores.
Can I somehow get those conditions into a stream instead of using a method like I did?

Comment: probably better to leave it as a method

Comment: Yes you can, but that would make this code less readable, without any important improvement. I would also suggest to move `x.getTaskResults().values().stream().mapToDouble(Integer::doubleValue).average().orElse(0)` to its own separate method.

Comment: Also `marks` doesn't need anything from *instance* on which it is called which means it should be `static` method, OR moved to class which holds/generates `Double d` value so you wouldn't need to provide `Double d` as its argument.

Comment: On an unrelated note as long as the tests are done in descending order of grades you don't  need the first condition of subsequent tests.  And since you are returning upon success you don't need to use else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I somehow get those conditions into a stream instead of using a method like I did?

You can move the logic of your `marks` method in to the stream and get rid of your marks method like below. But like others already mentioned in the comments, only because you can doesn't mean you should

```
public Map<Person, String> defineMarks(Stream<CourseResult> results) {
    return results.collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                    CourseResult::getPerson,
                    x -> {
                        double avg = x.getTaskResults().values().stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue)).getAverage();
                        if(avg >  90) return "A";
                        if(avg >= 83) return "B";
                        if(avg >= 75) return "C";
                        if(avg >= 68) return "D";
                        if(avg >= 60) return "E";
                        else return "F";
                    }
            ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will consider leaving marks method tho I think in my case I'd rather have that logic in stream since it's a streams exercise.

Comment: If I have another question related to this method should I make a new post or edit this one? I don't really know yet how things are done on this site.

Comment: @fireballun Changing already asked question into new one would invalidated already posted answers. So new problem should be asked in new question.